# How to compare IP addresses in Kibana script fields with CIDR notation?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Is it possible to create a Kibana script field that compares values of IP addresses using a CIDR notation? Or I just can do that with regex matches, considering IP fields as strings?

For example, I want to return all external addresses in netflow data, to be used in another case. The data has source.ip and destination.ip. My network is 192.168.0.0/24 and I want all other different addresses.

**The following comparison does not work (just an example).**

```
if (doc['source.ip'].value == "192.168.0.0/24") { 
    return doc['destination.ip'].value;
} else {
    return doc['source.ip'].value;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: 1. do this in logstash is better 2. Setting a flag indicates that the IP is reversed 3.I am trying

Comment: I'm not using logstash. I'm using filebeat and flows are directly inserted in elastic search.

Answer (score 0):

The es script field IP is of type string only, so ... it is just eg.

```
if (doc['source.ip'].value.indexOf('192') || doc['source.ip'].value.indexOf('172.16') || 
|| ... || doc['source.ip'].value.indexOf('172.31')) { # if you want more...
    return doc['destination.ip'].value;
} else {
    return doc['source.ip'].value;
}
```

We have a similar situation, add a flag in logstash to indicate that the connection is reversed.

Comment: The goal is not to detect reserved addresses. I would like to detect any class of address (in my case, all addresses that isn't mine). So, this is why I'm looking for a comparison using CIDR notation, not a string one.